# Send list in body of Gatling post method

Tags: request, performance-testing, gatling

I am trying to send a LIST as post request via gatling but it is not working as expected. I tried same with postman and it is working as expected.

Request which I am sending from gatling:

```
http("Calling the endpoint)
.post("url")
.header("headers)
.body(StringBody("""
[{"input1":"vaue1"
"input2":"value2"},
{"input3":"vaue3"

}]
"""))
```

Is it because, I am trying to send stringBody when the server is expecting List inputs.

I tried same inputs via post man and it worked.

When I see the application log, I see empty body is sent when it is sent from Gatling.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add jsonStringify() in the end of the string before sending POST request.

```
http("Calling the endpoint)
.post("url")
.header("headers)
.body(StringBody(
[{"input1":"vaue1"
"input2":"value2"},
{"input3":"vaue3"

}].jsonStringify()
))
```